# How can I check if a matrix is positive definite without using NumPy?

Tags: python-3.x, linear-algebra

I am performing the Choleski Decomposition of a matrix and would like to check if the matrix is symmetric and positive definite without using mumpy.linalg.

Will using the numpy.isclose function work?

Comment: You can find a pure Python implementation of the Cholesky decomposition [here](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Cholesky-Decomposition-in-Python-and-NumPy/). You may also look at the [source of scipy.linalg.cholesky](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.1/scipy/linalg/_decomp_cholesky.py#L45-L91).